# Switching between contact numbers depending on Wifi connectivity in Android phone

Tags: java, call

Can we have an android application which will direct any incoming call to

a) the cell number in case wifi is disabled 
b) office extension number through Jabber client in case wifi is connected (when I am in office I want to receive calls on my extension instead of cell).

Is there any Jabber client is available which has such settings, or I need to develop an android application(In java) which can achieve this.